# Why the Pink textures? Not Packed but called from a source file

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

So I wanted to make a Blender game and I've been working on the exterior now suddenly after about three days of working on it, Blender will no longer call the textures I need it to and I wind up with this, which is completely undesirable. The textures for some reason show in the materials tab but not in the textures tab nor in the Materials viewing pane. Is there a way to fix this? Preferably permanently so that it doesn't happen again?

[image]

Comment: Did you move the textures or the .blend file to a different Dir?

Comment: The textures have never been moved out of their C:\Program Files\3DGAME\Textures

Directory, I have however moved the .Blend file many times and this has never happened before.

Comment: By default blender will not save the images as part of the file. If you moved the blender file and the images are being referenced using relative paths blender will not find them in the expected folder any longer.  You need then to use absolute paths. If you want to make the images part of the file you have to pack them. File>External Data>Pack_All_Into_,blend